# Collapsable/Accordion like view in iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiwebview, accordion

I am trying to develop a collapsable/accordion like feature in my iOS app.  This would be your typical FAQ type feature that would be found on web sites.  I would like to tap the heading and then the detail is displayed.

Since this is for the help section and there are only a few items I thought I would be super simple to embed an HTML file with some JS in it to perform the action and render it in a web view.  I got that to work without an issue.  It loads and works great.  However, with the web view I can 'bounces'/pull down the view to reveal the background of the main view.  Now, this would not be a problem normally but since the designers use some gradients it looks awful.  I set bounces to false and all is well but not super smooth when scrolling.

Here is an [example of the accordion](http://drew5.net/examples/accordion-example/advice.html) I am talking about.

I then found this [project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/iPhone/collapsabletableview.aspx).

Which is a little more on the right track.  But the table view height stays fixed and does not act like the other accordion view.

My question is this....am I missing something?  Should I be looking at a different design pattern?  Any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never found the answer.  I ended up creating a basic master - details table view instead.

I created an array with 4 dictionary objects.  Each object has a title and an array of the items for the details.

My main table view is showing the 4 dictionary object titles and the detail view is showing the rest of the array elements.  Seems fine.  I was hoping to find a dynamically sizing table view but no such luck.  Maybe for the next release.